# R fill a matrix according to condition, error

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to fill a matrix with following condition:

```
id<-c(1:10)
start<-c(2,5,5,6,6,7,8,9,9,10)
stop<-c(3,6,8,8,9,8,10,10,10,10)
df<-cbind(id,start,stop)

mat<-matrix(0,ncol = length(start), nrow = length(id))
colnames(mat)<-c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","A9","A10")
rownames(mat)<-id
```

Condition:

```
 for(i in 1:length(id)) mat[i,which(colnames(mat) == start[i]):which(colnames(mat) == stop[i])]=1
```

But I receive always an error: "Error in which(colnames(mat) == start[i]):which(colnames(mat) == stop[i]) :
Argument of length 0"

I can't find an error. What am I doing wrong?

Expected output:

[image]
Thank You in advance.

Comment: Can you show the expected output? `c(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,A10)` is supposed to be a character vector I guess? I.e. `c("A1", "A2", ...`

Comment: I believe you are looking for `for(i in 1:length(id)) { mat[i,start[i]:stop[i]] <- 1 }`.

Comment: Yes, You are right. I have already corrected it.

Comment: Martin Gal, It works! Thank You very much.

Comment: Two hints: `id <- c(1:10)` is simplified to `id <- 1:10`. `colnames(mat) <- paste0("A", 1:10)`.

Comment: Nice to know. Thank You!